# does the ant pattern "**/**.jar" always represent the same set of files as "**/*.jar" and "**.jar"?

Tags: java, ant

Since ** matches any number of path segments and separators, can it be safely assumed that the following ant patterns will always match the same set of files?

```
**/**.jar
**/*.jar
**.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'**/**.jar'` and `'**/*.jar'` matches all files and directories containing .jar files throughout the file directory tree. i.e. including sub-directories as well

`**.jar` matches all .jar files only in the current directory. This pattern will not match all .jar files throughout the file directory tree. it will just look only in the base directory and not in the sub-directories in the file directory tree. Hope this helps

Comment: Then what's the difference between `**.jar` and `*.jar`?

Comment: there is no difference at all